# INSERT INTO WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I know that you can't INSERT INTO with a WHERE clause, and that the better route to go is an UPDATE statement. However with my situation, the table itself does not have the preexisting entry to update.

I'm working with two tables, "accounts" and "loginnames". I have an initial statement that takes user input (login name preference) and creates and entry in loginnames (id, name) table with an autoincremented column of "id".

I then have a secondary statement that queries the loginnames table searching for the new entry, and then inserts various data in the secondary table (accounts), using the linked id column.

Id like to create a statement similar to the following but I'm being met with an error of having INSERT and WHERE.

`INSERT INTO accounts (id, field1, field2, field3) VALUES (id, "data", "data", "data") WHERE id FROM loginNames = '$USER';`

Comment: Search `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got that information from, but you can use a WHERE clause in MySQL INSERT statements according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html#:%7E:text=The%20target%20table%20of%20the%20INSERT%20statement%20may,from%20the%20%20same%20table%20in%20a%20subquery.).

```
INSERT INTO
SELECT
FROM
WHERE
```

Comment: With that looking close to what I'm going for, I'm unsure how to pass the the id found from the WHERE clause into the select part of the statement. 

```accounts (id, field1, field2, field3)```

Comment: Have you tried assigning a variable where you capture the username before running the INSERT statement? You can pass the variable into the statement.

Comment: My issue that I'm having is utilizing these statements through Webmin.  The problem was between sql queries, I'm losing the variable :/ So I was attempting to do it in a single string to bypass the variable issue.